# Visual Studio Generate Database from DBContext and classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I've created my classes or models for my database and finally got a DataContext class working with relational mapping, now I want to know if you can generate the database in visual studio with those classes before I proceed inserting adding updating and deleting etc with web pages. The reason is I want to check the databases relationships in the tables. If you can could you leave a detailed explanation of what to do or if you know an article which demonstrates this could post the link thanks.

Comment: Try it yourself. Access a collection of your dbContext in your page and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

[Using Entity Framework Code First Approach with Fluent API in an ASP.NET MVC application](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=899)